# Qt WebAssembly (android chrome portrait orientation black screen issue)

Tags: android, qt, google-chrome, webassembly

I have Qt 5.13.1 with emscripten 1.38.27.
I have an app builded with Qt for WebAssembly (my main version of app is made with Qt widgets).
Chrome browser (for Android) in portrait orientation displays black screen. But when it is in landscape orientation it displays app normally (so i can see my interface and interact with it).

I tried my app on Firefox, Safari, Chrome for desktop - works like a charm.
Also no problems with Firefox and Safari on phones.

I disabled hardware acceleration in android browser, but it didn`t give any results.

Looks like i have to implement some special functionality for android chrome browser or i have to set additional settings in chrome browser.

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank`s in advance!